# duplicate row based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to duplicate row based on cell value then delete the cell value(in red) so that when rerun the script wont work on the same row again

I've tried script but it has 2 problems

1- the cell value remain so when rerun script it will cause duplication of same row again and again
2- remove the formulas that I wrote from the entire sheet

the script if you want to check it is still exist in appscript
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fJc2ymAADaZ4jtEGRAkUkWRape24Un7OE4jYcgcd9FM/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Auto Dupe for Single Row**

```
function AutoDuplicate() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var bA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var v=[];
  var b=[]
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var t1=bA[i][7];
    var t2=vA[i][7];
    if(bA[i][7]=='#ff0000' && !isNaN(vA[i][7]) && Number(vA[i][7])>0) {
      bA[i][7]='#ffffff';
      for(var j=0;j<vA[i][7];j++) {
        v.push(vA[i]);
      }
      b.push(bA[i]);
      sh.getRange(1,1,v.length,v[0].length).setValues(v);
      sh.getRange(1,1,b.length,b[0].length).setBackgrounds(b);
    }
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]

**Auto Dupe For Multiple Rows**

```
function autoDupeForMultipleRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getDisplayValues();
  var bA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var v=[];
  var b=[];
  var a=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(bA[i][7]=='#ff0000' && !isNaN(vA[i][7]) && Number(vA[i][7])>0) {
      bA[i][7]='#ffffff';
      for(var j=0;j<=vA[i][7];j++) {
        v.push(vA[i]);
        b.push(bA[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  sh.clearContents();
  var org=sh.getRange(1,1,v.length,v[0].length).setValues(v);
  org.setBackgrounds(b);
}
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Your example only showed one row and the duplicates were only applied to row one.  So you need to change your description so that we can understand what you really want.  I did what you described.

Comment: I see, that's beutiful thank you very much  I saw the animation it wil do the job, I really apreace it